# As an engineer, how do I know where I'm needed?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

If I want to go around fixing things as an engineer as they're ninja'ed (or whatever the proper ND parlance is), can I see the health of structures on the map somehow?  How do I know where I should go to torch things?

Comment: Look for the idiots yelling NEEDA DISPENSA HEAH. Oh, wrong game.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay close attention to the "Building under attack" alert and look at the red marker for where it happened (press M to toggle the minimap to display the whole map).

In many situations there are a lot of buildings under attack but as engineer you usually don't have to focus much on aiming at opponents and stuff, so you should be able to keep an eye on all the alerts and notice outliers.

Also, listen to your commander and tell him that you are rolling an engineer and that he can order you arround when neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall from the recent free weekend for this game, those semi-transparent building icons on your main HUD (not the radar) will begin to slowly fade to the repair icon and back periodically if they're in need of repairs.